# nodeJs returning QUOTED string instead of plain text using lambda AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The nodejs function is expected to return text/csv but instead returning quoted string with embedded newline character \n instead of real newline.

Using interceptor for headers received in response it states correctly 
content-type: text/csv
for request like GET /tst/items/name HTTP/1.1
 The nodejs snippet is

```
 const Json2csvP = require('json2csv').Parser;
 const fields = ['f1','f2','f3'];
var searchQ =['select * from names'];
 await db.any(searchQ[0])
        .then(function(data) {
           const json2csvP = new Json2csvP({ fields, quote: '', eol: '\n' });
            console.log(csv);
            callback(null, (csv));
        })
```

so for the console response in AWS output is like

```
"field1, field2 field3\n1  2  3"
```

and the caller in browser/REST tool get it

```
"field1, field2 field3\n1  2  3"
```

but I am looking the below csv format at callee side

```
field1 field2 field3
1  2   3
```

note there is no quote, and a real new line instead of \n character in plain text without html.I did tried using .split like below

```
 callback(null, (csv).split(/\n/g));
```

that give real newline only in AWS response result 
    ["field1 field2 field3",
        "1  2   3"]

but not in the format desired (without quotes in both line) and for the caller/ browser/REST tool , it gave like below without newline and with quotes and extra undesired [ and ] characters like like below.

```
["field1 field2 field3", "1  2   3"]
```

How can caller receive the below?

```
field1 field2 field3
    1  2   3
```

Comment: Everything is fine. AWS console is printing `"field1, field2 field3\n1  2  3"` probably because it's JSON-encoding the string. The data behind that textual representation ***is*** what you think (no quotes, with a "real" newline). Try the following in Node.js: `var fs = require('fs'); var csv = "field1, field2 field3\n1  2  3"; fs.writeFileSync('out.csv', csv);` and then look at `out.csv`. It matches your expectation. Everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, there is more on this and it is not ok for the caller like REST client that expect data  in desired format. The file get downloaded without using fs lib  in browser (see the header in response, it is text/csv) and when I open it both in notepad and notepad++, the output is a quoted string with embedded newline character. In browser(chrome) the page display quoted  string with embedded \n chacter. The same code in java or c# gave desired result but in nodejs, looks  somerhing is missing from  above code.

Comment: I see, then try `JSON.parse(theWeirdString)`, that should give you a plainly-coded string.

Comment: Yes, I tried JSON. parse and it gave null.

Comment: I got null because the input is a csv (not json) that is                        
var CSV_STRING = "'col1','col2','col3'\n'1','2','3'\n'4','5','6'";
  while the JSOn will parse if it is like  var JSON_STRING = '[{"col1":"1","col2":"2","col3":"3"},{"col1":"4","col2":"5","col3":"6"}]';     So I don't think the JSON.parse will work.

Comment: Your Lambda function is returning your output string as a *JSON string* because that is what Lambda functions always return -- *some kind of JSON*.  It sounds like you are using API Gateway, in which case, a [Lambda Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html) seems like what you should be using, because the response JSON object is deserialized by API Gateway and the `body` string from the response object would be returned to the caller, and it would look exactly as you expect.

Comment: Thanks Michael, as stated above, the lambda function written in java when returning correctly gave newline and string without quotes. I did tried to create in nodejs and it failed, So I think it is not aws lambda function issue for output but either nodejs limitation or we are missing something. I tried csv-string also, all print good in aws console.log but the same written value is changed on return from nodej code only.

Comment: As per AWS documentation, it appear to be nodejs and Aws combined limitation 9https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html0. This is not there for java and Aws combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did tried many nodejs modules for parsing, csv and streams etc. to get the desired ouput and none worked. The outuput is ALWAYS stringified.

As per AWS documentation, 
it appear to be nodejs and Aws combined limitation [`https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html)

> result – is an optional parameter that you can use to provide the
>   result of a successful function execution. The result provided must be
>   JSON.stringify compatible. If an error is provided, this parameter is
>   ignored

.

This limitation is not there for java and Aws combined.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-handler-types.html

> outputType – If you plan to invoke the Lambda function synchronously
>   (using the RequestResponse invocation type), you can return the output
>   of your function using any of the supported data types.